# Tymon JWTAuth for custom model which is not user model

Tags: laravel-5, json-web-token

I want to create JWT using client model. All the login credentials are saved in the clients table. Here in my Laravel 5.4 application I dont want to have users model. My piece of code is being showing. Now when I am trying to login laravel querying from users table which I don't. I want it from clients table. All the required namespaces I have added top in my controller file. Need help to get a solution.

```
\Config::set('jwt.user', 'App\Client'); 
        \Config::set('auth.providers.users.model', \App\Client::class);
        $credentials = ["username"=>$user_name,"password"=>$password];
        $token = null;
        try {
            if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json([
                    'response' => 'error',
                    'message' => 'invalid_email_or_password',
                ]);
            }
        } catch (JWTAuthException $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'response' => 'error',
                'message' => 'failed_to_create_token',
            ]);
        }
        return response()->json([
            'response' => 'success',
            'result' => [
                'token' => $token,
                'message' => 'I am front user',
            ],
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the providers => users => model => to your custom namespace in config/auth.php

Example

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,  <= change this to your custom namespace
    ],


],
```